# Parallel computing in Julia - running a simple for-loop on multiple cores

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

For starters, I have to say I'm completely new to parallel computing (and know close to nothing about computer science), so my understanding of what things like "workers" or "processes" actually are is very limited. I do however have a question about running a simple for-loop that presumably has no dependencies between the iterations in parallel.

Let's say I wanted to do the following:

```
for N in 1:5:20
    println("The N of this iteration in $N")
end
```

If I simply wanted these messages to appear on screen and the order of appearance didn't matter, how could one achieve this in Julia 0.6, and for future reference in Julia 0.7 (and therefore 1.0)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Distributed Processing

Start julia with e.g. `julia -p 4` if you want to use 4 cpus (or use the function `addprocs(4)`). In Julia 1.x, you make a parallel loop as following:

```
using Distributed
@distributed for N in 1:5:20
    println("The N of this iteration in $N")
end
```

Note that every process have its own variables per default.
For any serious work, have a look at the manual https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/parallel-computing/, in particular the section about SharedArrays.

Another option for distributed computing are the function `pmap` or the package `MPI.jl`.

## Threads

Since Julia 1.3, you can also use Threads as noted by wueli.
Start julia with e.g. `julia -t 4` to use 4 threads. Alternatively you can or set the environment variable `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` before starting julia.
For example  Linux/Mac OS:

```
export JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4
```

In windows, you can use `set JULIA_NUM_THREADS 4` in the cmd prompt.

Then in julia:

```
   Threads.@threads for N = 1::20
       println("N = $N (thread $(Threads.threadid()) of out $(Threads.nthreads()))")
   end
```

All CPUs are assumed to have access to shared memory in the examples above (e.g. "OpenMP style" parallelism) which is the common case for multi-core CPUs.

Comment: SharedArrays shouldn't be used with too serious work because you want to decrease the amount of communication, but it's a nice tool in areas which don't need the most performance. `pmap` and `@parallel`/`@distributed` both distribute work among different computers: it's just a matter of setting up processes on different computers and having an SSH connection. And the most speed will come from `Threads.@threads`. If you need to print from threads you need to use `Core.print` though.

Answer (score 15):

Just to add the example to the answer of Chris. Since the release of julia 1.3 you do this easily with `Threads.@threads`

```
Threads.@threads for N in 1:5:20
    println("The number of this iteration is $N")
end
```

Here you are running only one julia session with multiple threads instead of using `Distributed` where you run multiple julia sessions.

See, e.g. [multithreading blog post](https://julialang.org/blog/2019/07/multithreading) for more information.