# Parallel Processing for nested loops in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to implement parallel processing for nested loops. However I am getting the following syntax error.

I am modifying the example from here ( [Parallel computing in Julia - running a simple for-loop on multiple cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51459459/parallel-computing-in-julia-running-a-simple-for-loop-on-multiple-cores) )

**This works**

```
for N in 1:5:20, H in 1:5:20
           println("The N of this iteration in $N, $H")
end
```

**This is giving syntax error**

```
using Distributed

@distributed for N in 1:5:20, H in 1:5:20
           println("The N of this iteration in $N, $H")
       end
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@distributed` macro supports iterating only over one parameter. Hence you could do:

```
@distributed for (N,H) in collect(Iterators.product(1:5:20,1:5:20))
    println("The N of this iteration in $N, $H")
end
```

Another option is of course having a nested loop. In that case only one of the loops should be `@distributed`.

Comment: Can I ask a follow up question @Przemyslaw Szufel? You said "Another option is of course having a nested loop. In that case only one of the loops should be `@distributed`". Technically, it seems that we can add @distributed to both loops?

Comment: Technically you can. But what is the point doing so? The outer loop would be just used to redistribute the inner. My bet is also that such processing pattern is not so well tested neither.  Perhaps if you have some more complex distributed processing patterns you would consider using Dagger.jl?

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I was hoping adding to both loops somehow make a better use of CPU. But I am still trying to understand what the computer will do in this case.

Comment: the CPU usage problem arises from: (1) process saturation by a single job (2) variance of job times. Basically (1) cannot be addressed by `Distributed` package alone and (2) could be but often requires lots of creativity when you stick to `Distributed`  only. But this is a subject for a new question.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative (for single node, multi core parallelization) would be multithreading. This is often easier / more efficient due to lower overhead and shared memory (note that there is no such thing like a Python GIL in Julia).
The corresponding Julia commands are `Threads.@threads` (in front of for loops) or `Threads.@spawn` for spawning tasks to be executed parallel.

Edit: example added

```
Threads.@threads for (N,H) in collect(Iterators.product(1:5:20,1:5:20))
    println("The N of this iteration in $N, $H")
end
```

2nd case:

```
f(x) = x^2
futures = [Threads.@spawn f(x) for x=1:10]
fetch.(futures)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example please ?

Comment: examples added above