# Understanding Julia multi-thread / multi-process design

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, julia

I would like to convert some of my code for scattering problem in MATLAB, and python to Julia. But after 1 day of reading docs, searching in Phind and reading posts like this [Parallel computing in Julia - running a simple for-loop on multiple cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51459459/parallel-computing-in-julia-running-a-simple-for-loop-on-multiple-cores) I still cannot understand Julia's Parallelism, neither MATLAB for that matter.

TL;DR: Let's forget about MATLAB vs Julia comparison. Someone please explain me why @distributed is 3 to some times 4 times faster than @threads here. If you want to know what led me to this question or copy the following code, please read the rest. Thank you.

[image: threads vs distributed]

In Julia's Manual we can see:

> Julia's multi-threading provides the ability to schedule Tasks simultaneously on more than one thread or **CPU core**, sharing memory. This is usually **the easiest way to get parallelism on one's PC** or on a **single large multi-core server**. Julia's multi-threading is composable. When one multi-threaded function calls another multi-threaded function, Julia will schedule all the threads globally on available resources, without oversubscribing.
> https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/parallel-computing/

If I understand it correctly, all it says is that when there is only "1" server, parallelism can be achieved by means of threads. So if someone wants to convert Matlab parfor loop to its Julia equivalent, then @threads will do the job, right? Wrong!

Imagine I want to convert this Matlab (2023a) code to Julia (1.9.2) code:

```
tic
k = zeros(10000, 100, 100);
for i = 1:10000 
    k(i, :, :) = rand(100, 100)*rand(100, 100)* ...
    rand(100, 100)*rand(100, 100)*rand(100, 100)* ...
    rand(100, 100)*rand(100, 100)*rand(100, 100)*...
    rand(100, 100)*rand(100, 100);
end
toc
```

The equivalent is (roughly) the following (@fastmath makes the performance worse):

```
function f()
     k = zeros(10000, 100, 100)
     @simd for i = 1:10000
     @inbounds k[i, :, :] = rand(Float64, (100, 100))*rand(Float64, (100, 100))*
                            rand(Float64, (100, 100))*rand(Float64, (100, 100))*
                            rand(Float64, (100, 100))*rand(Float64, (100, 100))*
                            rand(Float64, (100, 100))*rand(Float64, (100, 100))*
                            rand(Float64, (100, 100))*rand(Float64, (100, 100));
    end
    return k
end

@time t = f();
```

I am not using @btime, because after setting `BenchmarkTools.DEFAULT_PARAMETERS.samples = 1` it crashes my Jupyter Lab (and also Vscode without Jupyter) for some reason.

Anyway my expectation was getting roughly the same amount of execution time after compiling Julia's code once, even though all I am hearing and seeing is that Julia's "for" loop is faster.That is wrong though. Matlab version is much more performant on my Intel Cori 7 8550U (it has 4 cores, and 8 logical threads), roughly 15~20% faster. So I looked at my CPU and saw that Matlab utilizes some form of parallelism automatically, using ~90% of CPU. So I told myself, maybe MATLAB JIT is clever, and I am comparing apples to oranges, so I changed Julia's code to the following:

```
function f()
     k = zeros(10000, 100, 100)
     Threads.@threads for i = 1:10000
     @inbounds k[i, :, :] = rand(Float64, (100, 100))*rand(Float64, (100, 100))*
                            rand(Float64, (100, 100))*rand(Float64, (100, 100))*
                            rand(Float64, (100, 100))*rand(Float64, (100, 100))*
                            rand(Float64, (100, 100))*rand(Float64, (100, 100))*
                            rand(Float64, (100, 100))*rand(Float64, (100, 100));
    end
    return k
end

@time t = f();
```

And I got almost the same performance! "Ok, that is it", I told myself, so matlab uses parallelism underhood automatically, Julia doesn't do that. It is fine. But I was wrong. So I changed Matlab code to

```
tic
k = zeros(10000, 100, 100);
parfor i = 1:10000 
    k(i, :, :) = rand(100, 100)*rand(100, 100)* ...
    rand(100, 100)*rand(100, 100)*rand(100, 100)* ...
    rand(100, 100)*rand(100, 100)*rand(100, 100)*...
    rand(100, 100)*rand(100, 100);
end
toc
```

and it became 4 times faster than before! But wait, wasn't matlab already using parallelism? Why this code is faster then? We come back to that later. Let's talk about Julia for now. So I had just followed documentation, wrote down a parallel code that I thought would be as performant as Matlab code, but MATLAB ended up being 4 times faster in the end. What was wrong? After a bit of digging, I changed Julia's code to the following:

```
addprocs(8)
function f()
    k = SharedArray{Float64}(10000, 100, 100)
     @sync @distributed for i = 1:10000
     @inbounds k[i, :, :] = rand(Float64, (100, 100))*rand(Float64, (100, 100))*
                            rand(Float64, (100, 100))*rand(Float64, (100, 100))*
                            rand(Float64, (100, 100))*rand(Float64, (100, 100))*
                            rand(Float64, (100, 100))*rand(Float64, (100, 100))*
                            rand(Float64, (100, 100))*rand(Float64, (100, 100));
    end
    return k
end

@time t = f();
```

And got the same performance as parfor Matlab code. Ok so far so good, when one wants to achieve parallelism, they should use @distributed then. But

1. what is up with Julia documentation then? Why does it sound as if when we have 1 server/pc, @threads would be some how equivalent to @distributed? I am not the only one confused by these macros, and all suggestion I see on internet is using both of them to see which one works better for a given problem! Here some examples:
   https://www.reddit.com/r/Julia/comments/cynbbb/question_multiprocessing_vs_multithreading/
   https://discourse.julialang.org/t/overhead-of-distributed-module-vs-threads/21588
   This makes no sense though. There should be one proper way of doing things, for a given problem. I understand more eccentric macros like @fastmath may need testing, but it makes no sense to me that there is no "proper" way of parallelism in Julia. Maybe there is, but I cannot understand it from documentation.
2. Why Julia doesn't use this multi-threading thing under-hood, just like MATLAB does? Is there some kind of language limitation, or is it by design like this, if so why? Now, every time that I want to convert some non-parallel (without parfor) MATLAB code to Julia I need to add @threads to get the same performance. Isn't this redundancy?
3. It does not make sense to me that normal MATLAB loop, or multi-threaded Julia's code, both use almost 4 cores, yet somehow MATLAB parfor or multi-process Julia code, out perform them significantly (4 times!) in term of speed. I mean, in both scenarios they are using same amount of resources (CPU wise, not Ram), so where this performance gain comes from?! I have 24GB RAM so it is not a bottleneck here.

And yes, I literally started learning Julia yesterday, so go easy on me.

Comment: Your code isn't really a very good test of language performance, since everything is array allocation and random number generation + matrix product BLAS calls. For-loop performance, for example, will be completely irrelevant here, since each loop iteration does so much heavy work. You are mostly comparing BLAS library performance. The BLAS calls are anyway multi-threaded in both languages by default, so parallelization performance on top of this will be hard to interpret.

Comment: BTW, both Matlab and Julia arrays are column major, so assigning and slicing in the trailing dimensions (as in `k[i, :, :] = `) is highly suboptimal. `k[:, :, i] = ` is preferable.

Comment: @DNF I am just trying to convert my scattering problem code, which is bunch of matrix multiplication in a long loop. I want an acceptable performance, nothing fancy, out performing other languages. It is just that I can't make sense of documentation, neither the answer given here, because it is totally opposite of my experience. But thank you for advise about Julia being column major. I see no difference in matlab speed however, though in practice k[:, :, i] makes the code much more readable.

Comment: The expectation that Julia should be faster than MATLAB is caused by the Julia developers being dishonest when they designed the benchmarks that they used to substantiate their claim of Julia being fast. Fact is, MATLAB is also very fast, and hard to beat when dealing with matrices.

Comment: If it's mainly a bunch of matrix multiplications, then you won't get much performance improvement from Julia. Matlab just calls MKL for matrix operations, and that's that.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Your comment is both false and misleading. The benchmarks were deliberately designed to test the performance of _language features_ and were appropriate for that purpose. Julia is absolutely faster than Matlab, but of course that difference is invisible when you are just calling C or Fortran code. If you didn't have BLAS, but had to implement matrix multiplications in native Matlab, it would be very slow. Native Julia implementations on the other hand matches BLAS.

Comment: @dnf you must not have experience with MATLAB, or maybe it’s experience from 10+ years ago before MATLAB had a good JIT. Those benchmarks were designed to make MATLAB look slow, and if you run those benchmarks today, instead of using results from 10+ years ago, you’ll see MATLAB is not slow.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have 25 years of continuous unbroken experience with Matlab, and use it several hours every day at work, always the latest version (in fact, often pre-release version). It is my main work tool. Julia is my hobby tool. Matlab performance is much improved over the past decade, but still relies on calling fast languages. The jit is nice but only works efficiently in some circumstances. General performance is very far from Julia, which is as fast as C or Fortran in many cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In computing (using Julia syntax in point below) you have the following parallelism types:

- `@simd` - utilize Single instruction, multiple data (SIMD) feature of a CPU
- `@async` - coroutines aka green threads (good for IO parallelization)
- `@threads` - multithreading, requires seting `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` environment variable or `-t` parameter when starting Julia
- `@distributed` - multiprocessing on a single or multiple machines, need to use `-p` julia command line option or `--machine-file` option or `addprocs()` command
- GPU computing - perhaps start with CUDA.jl

Now having this knowledge I briefly answer your equations:

#### Ad 1.

Multi-threading is on a single machine.

Multi-processing can occur on a single machine or multiple machines.

Multiprocessing on multiple machines is called distribute computing. Julia has basically the same API for multiprocessing and distributed computing - both are available via `using Distributed`

Finally note that in multi-processing a process can be single or multi-threaded.

The above concepts are not specific to Julia in any way (although Julia has nice APIs to achieve such functionality).
You definitely should have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#Threads_vs_processes

#### Ad 2.

Julia BLAS for linear algebra is using multi-threading independently of Julia configuration, try `LinearAlgebra.BLAS.get_num_threads()`. Some other Julia libraries use multi-threading and this depends on the value of `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` environment variable or `-t` parameter.
So several libraries use it under-the-hood.
However writing a multi-threaded code (in any programming language, Julia included) is difficult due to possible code parallelization problems such as deadlocks, thread chase or false sharing. It is not auto-magical and requires several hours spent on understanding the concepts.

#### Ad. 3.

Julia code outperform MATLAB's code. However writing a performant code is not easy. Perhaps start with testing yourself all codes from this list: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/
For the code that you are running here `Threads.@threads` seems to be the best approach (assuming that you plan to use around 8-16 threads).

### Note on the code

If you run this long enough your main problem are allocations. You could use in-place multiplication and hence allocate much less memory (and have less garbage collector events).

```
begin
    Y = Matrix{Float64}(undef, 100, 100)
    A = rand(100,100)
    B = Matrix{Float64}(undef, 100, 100)
    for i = 1:10
        rand!(B)
        mul!(Y,A,B)
        if i < 10
            A .= Y
        end
    end
    Y
end;
```

The code above has `(6 allocations: 234.52 KiB)` while normal multiplication `(38 allocations: 1.45 MiB)`. This will make a noticeable difference when the workload is huge.

#### EDIT

> Just tell me why distributed is 4 time faster than threads in Julia

OK this is tricky. There are few possible reasons (and most likely they combine for the observed behavior):

- Your code is performing a huge number of allocations which is kicking-in the garbage collector. It is always easier to perform garbage collection on 8 separate disconnected processes than on a single multi-threaded one. When lots of garbage collection is involved it might be better to use `@distributed` than `Threads.@threads`. Additionally, from my empirical observations, beyond 8 jobs in Julia processes seem to scale better than threads. That is why you should consider in-place operations (`LinearAlgebra.mul!`) as suggested by myself and DNF
- as noted by myself and DNF `LinearAlgebra.BLAS` is not composable with threading mechanism. This means that 8 processes are in the end utilizing eg. a total 32 threads (depending on your machine). This combined with the garbage collector makes the multi-threaded and distributed scenarios harder to compare.

In conclusion, for garbage collector-heavy-jobs you will generally see a better performance with multi-processing (`using Distributed`) than multi-threading.

#### EDIT 2

MATLAB is using MKL and MersenneTwister. When making benchmark it might be worth writing the Julia code the same way.

Multiplying two rands (uses Xoshori 256++ and OpenBLAS) yields the following result )

```
julia> @btime rand(100,100)*rand(100,100);
  118.500 μs (6 allocations: 234.52 KiB)
```

Let's try MersenneTwister and MKL (see also https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/MKL.jl ):

```
julia> using MKL, Random

julia> mt = MersenneTwister();

julia> @btime rand($mt, 100,100)*rand($mt, 100,100);
  68.900 μs (6 allocations: 234.52 KiB)
```

Worth knowing that changing this code to MKL and MT is a 2x speed up.

Comment: In addition to these points, Matlab also uses MKL BLAS by default, while Julia uses OpenBLAS. This could also cause considerable differences in performance, but can be fixed by using MKL.jl

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but If distributed and threads were to give me roughly the same performance, I wouldn't have even asked this question. But distributed outperforms threads. It is 4 times faster. And yes, I have started Julia with -t 8 otherwise I couldn't have seen better performance of threads compare to normal for loop. From your answer, it seems that you are suggesting the opposite of my experience. so are you saying it is machine dependent, then? I really can't see how your reply answer my question, (but the fact that libraries use multi-threading was useful info).

Comment: I read your answer a few times. But it answer none of my questions (albeit it does contain a lot of good info). The first and second part is basically what I have quoted from Julia's Manual it self, and as for ad.3 it has literally nothing to do with my question. Maybe you just skimmed over my question because everyone ask this type of question? Please forget about MATLAB completely. Just tell me why distributed is 4 time faster than threads in Julia. That will do.

Comment: @ParadoxyIf If you want to speed up your code, you should pre-allocate your matrices and use in-place `LinearAlgebra.mul!` for better performance. Your use of `rand` in the question is confusing, is this part of the actual algorithm? If it is, pre-allocate and use in-place `rand!` instead. If it isn't, then you are masking performance issues by spending lots of time on `rand`. There are also possible issues with `rand` and multi-threading, which you may have to consider.

Comment: “Julia code outperform MATLAB's code.” This statement is based on dishonest benchmarking by the developers of Julia. The large amount of questions on here about why Julia is not as fast as MATLAB clearly disprove this statement. Answers always have to jump through hoops to write Julia code that matches MATLAB’s performance.

Comment: @DNF Thank you, yes I saw that suggestion in Przemyslaw Szufel's answer as well. Will do. But it doesn't address threads vs distributed question, the main point of this topic. About rand, no it is not part of algorithm, I just wrote it to illustrate the problem. Remember that any speed gain that I can get by changing rand (to rand! or anything else) would show itself in both of threads and distributed. So it really doesn't matter. Forget about MATLAB completely, see the picture I added to my question. Maybe it makes things more clear. I bet there are some unsaid assumption for threads

Comment: @Paradoxy BLAS is using multiple threads, and that threading model is separate and not composable with Julia's threads, in other words using `@threads` and BLAS together is not likely to be beneficial for performance. You could try setting the number of BLAS threads to 1, but it might not be a net benefit. I never use Distributed, but it may have less of those issues.

Comment: @DNF Hmmm, but I am not using LinearAlgebra library at all. So I cannot see how BLAS affects anything, when I am not using it. Are you suggesting Julia itself automatically calls BLAS on each matrix multiplication? How should I set number of thread in BLAS, without building it from source?

Comment: All `Matrix` multiplications in Julia uses BLAS, that is not tied to the LinearAlgebra stdlib. I referred to `LinearAlgebra.mul!` as a way of improving performance by avoiding unnecessary allocations.

Comment: @Paradoxy I added a comment that might help. The aforementioned BLAS behavior + heavy reliance of this code on the garbage collection makes this example to compare many different aspects at once and it is harder to isolate to discuss the differences.  BTW you can switch Julia to MKL too (which is what MATLAB has)

Comment: Note that Julia can be used MKL + the same RNG as MATLAB. I added an edit to show what happens then (2x speedup in a small micro benchmark)

Comment: I changed my Julia code according to your and @DNF suggestions. It did experience a big speed up, but in an unexpected way, for example MKL has worse performance in distributed for some reason. Nevertheless I learnt a lot of things today. I posted whatever I got below.

Answer (score 0):

My original post became super long, therefore I will add some of my insights here, thanks to @DNF and @Przemyslaw Szufel who helped me to learn some important aspects of this language.

1. There is a huge difference between MATLAB and Julia which is not explicitly mentioned here https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/noteworthy-differences/, and that is the fact that any function call would allocate some data in the memory, instead of overwriting existing data. Here is an example:

```
@time begin
    A = Matrix{Float64}(undef, 100, 100)
    for i = 1:10
        A .= rand(100, 100)
    end
end
0.000797 seconds (32 allocations: 860.047 KiB)
```

Whereas

```
@time begin
    A = Matrix{Float64}(undef, 100, 100)
    for i = 1:10
        rand!(A)
    end
end
0.000138 seconds (2 allocations: 78.172 KiB)
```

It may be obvious for Julia's users, but coming from MATLAB, with the exception of Sparse Matrices, I cannot think of any similar scenario that works that way. For example in MATLAB

```
tic
A = zeros(100, 100);
for i = 1:10
    A = rand(100, 100);
end
toc
```

rand(100, 100) will immediately destroys zeros(100, 100) in the memory and replace it with new values. It doesn't allocate new space in memory, it overwrites it (and yes there is no need for zeros(100, 100) preallocation here). So the very concept of preallocation, even though exists in both languages, is in practice widely different. I wish there was a more clear hint in documentation.

2. Both Matlab JIT and Julia compiler can potentially convert normal for loop to a multi-threaded one under-hood. It seems Matlab is more aggressive in this respect, because it uses MKL. Nevertheless, I changed my Julia code according to suggestion given here to the followings:

```
function distribute()
    k = SharedArray{Float64}(100, 100, 10000)
    A = Matrix{Float64}(undef, 100, 100)
    B = Matrix{Float64}(undef, 100, 100)
    Y = Matrix{Float64}(undef, 100, 100)
    @inbounds @sync @distributed  for i = 1:10000
        rand!(A)
        for j = 1:9
                mul!(Y, A, rand!(B))
                A .= Y
        end
        k[:, :, i] = A
    end
    return k
end

distributed();
@time t = distribute();
2.671872 seconds (2.11 k allocations: 325.055 KiB)
```

```
function thread()
    k = Array{Float64}(undef, 100, 100, 10000)
    A = Matrix{Float64}(undef, 100, 100)
    B = Matrix{Float64}(undef, 100, 100)
    Y = Matrix{Float64}(undef, 100, 100)
    @inbounds Threads.@threads for i = 1:10000
        rand!(A)
        for j = 1:9
                mul!(Y, A, rand!(B))
                A .= Y
        end
        k[:, :, i] = A
    end
    return k
end
thread()
@time t = thread();
8.549158 seconds (59 allocations: 763.174 MiB, 0.07% gc time)
```

Even after solving allocations issue, @distributed still does beat @threads! I also tried using MKL. The results were interesting,

```
@everywhere using MKL
@time t = thread();
4.133106 seconds (633 allocations: 763.212 MiB, 0.29% gc time)
@time t = distribute();
4.689101 seconds (2.17 k allocations: 326.586 KiB)
```

I don't know how to make sense of that, MKL degerades @distributed speed significantly. Nevertheless, getting roughly the same speed in both scenarios gave me some peace. I also tried MersenneTwister, but I couldn't see any real difference in term of speed. distribute function without mkl beats MATLAB easily, by margin of 30% or something. With MKL however, I see no difference, which I probably shouldn't, which is a good thing.

Edit 1:

Turns out adding LinearAlgebra.BLAS.set_num_threads(1) makes a huge difference for thread function (see @PrzemyslawSzufel's comment below):

```
LinearAlgebra.BLAS.set_num_threads(1)
@time k = thread();
2.455945 seconds (344 allocations: 763.190 MiB, 0.04% gc time)
```

Comment: (1) I do not know Matlab, however I would bet with high chance that your Matlab code runs single-threaded but the Matlab MKL matrix multiplications are multi-threaded.  (2) You could also try `LinearAlgebra.BLAS.set_num_threads(1)` and see what happens with benchmark as the BLAS composabillity is separate form Julia's

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel Oh, I combined MKL + LinearAlgebra.BLAS.set_num_threads(1) + threads, and I got ~2.5 second, which is even faster than non-MKL distributed! Very interesting. Where can I learn this type of information?

Comment: This is a consequence of the fact that BLAS has a separate multithreading to Julia's multithreading. It is usually better to have the threading control in one place.