# How numpy arrays are overwritten from interpreter point of view?

Tags: python, numpy, intel-mkl

I wrote two simple functions to learn CPython's behaviour regarding numpy arrays.

Python 3.12.1 and numpy version 1.26.2, compiled by mkl (conda default)

```
def foo():
    for i in range(100):
        H = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)

%timeit -r 100 foo()
```

```
def baaz():
    H = np.zeros((1000, 1000))
    for i in range(100):
        H[:, :] = np.random.rand(1000, 1000)

%timeit -r 100 baaz()
```

Using dis library to see the bytecodes by calling dis.dis(foo()) an dis.dis(baaz()) I get these two outputs.

Initially, I believed that baaz() should run faster than than foo() since we are reusing the H array, instead of de-allocating, and allocating H again on each loop. However, I see consistently that foo() is faster. I am wondering what causes this. I cannot read <s>assembly</s> bytecode, but by simply looking at dis.dis(foo()) and dis.dis(baaz()) output, I can see that foo() generates 13 extra lines compare to baaz().

Dissembled foo():

```
    671           0 RETURN_GENERATOR
                  2 POP_TOP
                  4 RESUME                   0
    
    676           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
                  8 STORE_FAST               1 (lastline)
    
    677          10 LOAD_FAST                0 (code)
        -->      12 LOAD_ATTR                1 (NULL|self + co_lines)
                 32 CALL                     0
                 40 GET_ITER
            >>   42 FOR_ITER                23 (to 92)
                 46 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
                 50 STORE_FAST               2 (start)
                 52 STORE_FAST               3 (end)
                 54 STORE_FAST               4 (line)
    
    678          56 LOAD_FAST                4 (line)
                 58 POP_JUMP_IF_NOT_NONE     1 (to 62)
                 60 JUMP_BACKWARD           10 (to 42)
            >>   62 LOAD_FAST                4 (line)
                 64 LOAD_FAST                1 (lastline)
                 66 COMPARE_OP              55 (!=)
                 70 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE         1 (to 74)
                 72 JUMP_BACKWARD           16 (to 42)
    
    679     >>   74 LOAD_FAST                4 (line)
                 76 STORE_FAST               1 (lastline)
    
    680          78 LOAD_FAST                2 (start)
                 80 LOAD_FAST                4 (line)
                 82 BUILD_TUPLE              2
                 84 YIELD_VALUE              1
                 86 RESUME                   1
                 88 POP_TOP
                 90 JUMP_BACKWARD           25 (to 42)
    
    677     >>   92 END_FOR
    
    681          94 RETURN_CONST             1 (None)
            >>   96 CALL_INTRINSIC_1         3 (INTRINSIC_STOPITERATION_ERROR)
                 98 RERAISE                  1
    ExceptionTable:
      4 to 58 -> 96 [0] lasti
      62 to 70 -> 96 [0] lasti
      74 to 94 -> 96 [0] lasti
```

Dissembled baaz():

```
  1           0 RESUME                   0

  2           2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (np)
             12 LOAD_ATTR                3 (NULL|self + zeros)
             32 LOAD_CONST               1 ((1000, 1000))
             34 CALL                     1
             42 STORE_FAST               0 (H)

  3          44 LOAD_GLOBAL              5 (NULL + range)
             54 LOAD_CONST               2 (100)
             56 CALL                     1
             64 GET_ITER
        >>   66 FOR_ITER                43 (to 156)
             70 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

  4          72 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (np)
             82 LOAD_ATTR                6 (random)
            102 LOAD_ATTR                9 (NULL|self + rand)
            122 LOAD_CONST               3 (1000)
            124 LOAD_CONST               3 (1000)
            126 CALL                     2
            134 LOAD_FAST                0 (H)
            136 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            138 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            140 BUILD_SLICE              2
            142 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            144 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            146 BUILD_SLICE              2
            148 BUILD_TUPLE              2
            150 STORE_SUBSCR
            154 JUMP_BACKWARD           45 (to 66)

  3     >>  156 END_FOR
            158 RETURN_CONST             0 (None)
```

P.S: It may seem not obvious why one would think that baaz() should be faster, but this is indeed the case in a language like Julia [Understanding Julia multi-thread / multi-process design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76889908/understanding-julia-multi-thread-multi-process-design).

Comment: I can read assembly. Can you show it?

Comment: Interesting question. My first guess is that even in `baaz`, the `np.random.rand()` function allocates a fresh matrix each time.

Comment: you *always* create an auxiliary array in both cases: `np.random.rand(1000, 1000)`. You then do the *additional work* of updating an existing array. And indeed, in the first, you create one additional array at the beginning

Comment: @Dr.V it 100% does

Comment: Each call to `np.random.rand` creates an array. In `foo`, a reference to this array is assigned to `H` (fast operation). In `baaz` the whole data must be copied to the array object already referenced by `H` (slow).

Comment: I'm browsing, but don't find it: Is there a way with numpy/scipy/other to generate random numbers via an iterator? - To overcome this issue?

Comment: @Dr.V iterator-based solutions will put you squarely in Python space, so while it may be worth it from a memory perspective (although, possibly not, since internally numpy might just create an array with the iterator), it is almost certainly going to be slower.

Comment: @harold it's not assembly, it's CPython bytecode, but it's pretty easy to follow especially with the output of the dissasembler

Comment: @harold I corrected my wording, this is bytecode not assembely, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *both* cases you are creating a new array when you do `np.random.rand(1000, 1000)`, and then de-allocating it. In the `baaz` case, you are also going through the work up updating the initial array. Hence it is slower.

Numpy functions provide a way to avoid this, consider a simple case:

```
arr[:] = arr + 1
```

This *always* creates a new array, which is the result of the expression `arr + 1`. You could avoid this by using:

```
np.add(arr, 1, out=arr)
```

Just a quick example of the above:

```
In [31]: %%timeit -r 100 arr = np.zeros(1_000_000)
    ...: arr[:] = arr + 1
    ...:
    ...:
1.85 ms ± 375 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 100 runs, 100 loops each)

In [32]: %%timeit -r 100 arr = np.zeros(1_000_000)
    ...: np.add(arr, 1, out=arr)
    ...:
    ...:
418 µs ± 29.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 100 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Unfortunately, I don't think there is anything equivalent for `numpy.random` functions. Possibly, `numba` can help you here, not sure how optimized `np.random` is with it though. But it's worth taking a look at.